# ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTrainer' from 'transformers' on Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

so confused why i couldn't import TFTraniner in colab

I've tried :
!pip install TFTranier
!pip --upgrade transformers
and reinstall transformers

but still failed to import TFTranier in colab like in the screenshot
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONidu.png)

I was trying to follow the code from other people,they successfully import TFTranier from transformers[Origianl code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsk3a.png)

Answer (score 0):

TFTrainer is a separate package that your are trying to import through transformers.

Here an example of how you can import from TFTrainer:

```
from tftrainer import TrainArgument, Trainer
```

https://github.com/Nam-SW/TFTrainer

**Edit**

tftrainer is no longer supported in latest version of transfomers, try using an older version.

I tried one and it worked:

`!pip install transformers==4.18.0`

Now, import TFTrainer like this:

```
from transformers.trainer_tf import TFTrainer
```

Comment: I was trying to follow the code from other people, they successfully imported TFTranier from transformers, not from tftrainer package

Comment: check the edit, you can try an older version of transformers to use TFTrainer.